# Learner Question: Table woe. How to set a totals field on a table using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using JSX within a SharePoint Framework (React/TypeScript) to create a form.
I'm attempting to create a total field that matches the width of the other rows above it. But I don't want a field to the left of the total field apart from a label saying total. For example:
[image]

I've tried applying inline CSS:

```
<th style={{width:'100%'}}></th>
<th style={{wdith:'40px'}}></th>
```

This works only if I include a textfield to the left of the total column. To help explain here are a few rows from this table:

```
<table className={styles.table} >

           <tr>
         <th>{''}</th>

           <th style={{width:'100%'}}>{' '}</th>
            <th style={{width:'40px'}}>% Time</th>

              </tr>

              <tr>1
               <td><TextField
               name="DutResp1"
               value={this.state.DutResp1}
               onChange={this.handleChange}
                 />
               </td>
               <td ><TextField 
                name="DutRespTime1"
                value={this.state.DutRespTime1}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                </td>

               </tr>
              <tr>2
              <td><TextField
               name="DutResp2"
               value={this.state.DutResp2}
               onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
              </td>
              <td ><TextField
              name="DutRespTime2"
               value={this.state.DutRespTime2}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                 />
               </td>

              </tr>

               { <tr>3
               <td><TextField
                name="DutResp5"
               value={this.state.DutResp5}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
               </td>
               <td ><TextField
                  name="DutRespTime5"
                 value={this.state.DutRespTime5}
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                 />
               </td>

               </tr> }

                {<tr >
                 <td >1</td> //I DON'T WANT THIS 1 OR THE FIELD BELOW, I WANT IT TO SAY TOTALS!!!
                 <td ><TextField 
                  name="DutRespTimeTotal"
                  value={this.state.DutRespTimeTotal}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                   hidden={true}
                 />
                 </td>
                 <td ><TextField //THIS IS THE TOTALS FIELD, I WANT THIS!
                  name="DutRespTimeTotal"
                  value={this.state.DutRespTimeTotal}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                 />
              </td>

           </tr> }

         </table>
```

Please note that the CSS assigned to the `className={styles.table}` is just setting the `width:100%`.

I haven't tried everything but I'm close to giving up! Any help please.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to have the same number of columns in each row
- If you want the word "Totals" to be displayed in a table then it neeeds to be in a cell
- You can use the `colspan` attribute (accessed via the `colSpan` property) to make a cell span multiple columns

So:

```
<tr>
    <th colSpan="2"> Totals </th>
    <td> <TextField /> </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Quentin's answer (column-span) above, but I used a footer `<tfoot>`
with the following CSS:

```
.total{
    text-align: right;
    column-span: 2;

  }
```

But I also used inline CSS for the table headers as such:

```
    <th style={{width: '90%'}}>{' '}</th>
    <th style={{width:'40px'}}>% Time</th>
```

This was certainly not easy to figure out and took a lot of experimentation.